# Chipset supports 8gb of RAM but computer is 32bit?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, 32-bit, chipset

I have a Compaq Pressario SR1222NX that I am looking to upgrade the RAM on.  So the max supported RAM is for my computer is 4 GB.  This makes sense to me as the 32 bit address limit is 4GB.  However... [According to intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/27733/Intel-915G-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller), the chipset of my computer will support up to 8GB.  So I dug around a little bit more and found [This document from intel](http://download.intel.com/design/chipsets/applnots/30167003.pdf) that specifies that "[8000MB] exceeds a 32-bit address limit of 4 GB. In a 32-bit system, only the first 4 GB of memory will be
accessible".  Apparently, all I have to do is install a 64bit OS.  I am very doubtful of this as my computer has a 32bit Intel Pentium 4.  So, I am wondering if the 8gb of ram will work in my computer without modifications, and if not, what modification would I have to make?

Comment: Just because the chipset supports 8gb does not mean the bios will.

Comment: The statement in the document from Intel is simply incorrect. The 4GB limit on 32-bit operating systems is a virtual address limit, not a physical memory limit. They are frequently confused because some 32-bit operating systems also have a 4GB physical memory limit, but they are totally different limits. It's very unusual to see this kind of mistake on an Intel tech document though.

Answer (score 4):

32 bit systems have supported more than 4 GB of RAM for well over a decade, [through the use of PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension).

That said, [the specs say that your computer's maximum supported memory capacity is 4 GB](http://www.cnet.com/products/compaq-presario-sr1222nx-p4-515-2-93-ghz-256-mb-80-gb/specs/), so it's 4GB, and what the chipset supports doesn't much matter.  It might be a BIOS limitation, it might be that the system board only supports a maximum DIMM size of 1GB, it might even be that the system is so old they hadn't considered the existence of larger DIMMs.  Regardless, the better approach is to buy a new computer, rather than throwing money away upgrading this one.  It's over 10 years old, FFS.  That's beyond geriatric in computing terms.  It's almost an antique.

Answer (score 2):

The chipset supports *some* 64 bit chips, and if you had a 64 bit capable chip you certainly could. This chipset's around the time intel made the transition, and from checking a random sampling many of the chips it supports are 64 bit.

*However* at the time the system was released, 64 bit windows wasn't really a thing. I *suspect* most systems ran xp, and 64 bit support for XP was not too good.

That said, if its ddr2 *some* systems have issues with 2gb sticks, and you'd need 4 slots (so 4x2gb) to max it out IIRC.

So, it might work or it might not. However its a reasonable bet that if you have the slots, and the right type of ram, detected in the bios, and a 64 bit OS, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Compaq Presario SR1222NX will support only 4 GB ( 2 x  2 GB) despite what the chipset can support. The memory controller can hold up to 2 GB on each of the two slots. 8 GB is not possible with your system even with 64 Bit OS.