# Make IE open new window in different browser

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, browser, internet-explorer

Is there a way to make IE open new window in a different browser like chrome. 
Any new popup or whenever the site opens a new window it should open in chrome instead of IE.

I found this entry in the registry

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\https\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe\" %1"
```

and tried changing the path to chrome.exe, but it had no effect. I think the registry entry is used to set the default browser not what I think it does.
So any hack that can do this?
I have to visit a particular site which can only be opened in IE, but that site most of the time open other sites which do not have this restriction, but it ends up opening in IE, and I end up copying/pasting the url in a different browser everytime.

Comment: I have found no way other than dragging and dropping the link into the other browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new tab in Chrome or Firefox and drag the link from IE and drop it on the tab in the other browser like this:
[image: drag]
[image: drop]

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a way to make IE open new window in a different browser like chrome.

No, there isn't.

Comment: Any documents to back this answer up? This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Moab Can you find any documents to backup the fact that you can't use Chrome to open up Fallout 4 into a new Excel process? Right, you can't, because that's just fundamentally not how computers work.  If you want to back up the answer with an explanation of why, feel free, but "no" is the answer to this question.

Comment: But the question is to open a link, just with another browser. Not opening another program

Comment: @zer0c00l Same concept.  IE (or any other major browser) doesn't have the functionality to send a specific url or website to another program.  The most granularity you'll get is the ability to open all files (or links) of a certain type with a default application.  But what you asked, simply isn't functionality that was written into IE.

Comment: This answer by you is a good one...http://superuser.com/a/1079204/40928

Comment: @Moab I never claimed this was a good answer, but it is the correct one.  And again, you are both free and encouraged to spend a bunch of *your* time explaining the reasoning behind why this feature isn't included in IE, but I'm not going to spend mine on it.

Comment: Poor answers get down votes, oh and your attitude sucks.

Comment: I used the comments like you should have.